# how to create django form with multiplechoicefield and add those value to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

what I want to achieve is user will submit 3 inputs in the form 1) name 2) dropdown to select technician, 3) multiselect dropdown to select multiple products. Once the user submit the details
it will generate one lead  in database with value like name,foreignkey of selected technician and id of selected products in different table. I don't know how to achieve this below I have mentioned my approch to achieve what I want. Please let me know if the models need any changes and how I can write a view for the same.

models.py

```
class product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class technician(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class lead(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    technician = models.ForeignKey(technician,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True) #only single selection
    products = models.ManyToManyField(product) #user can select multiple product in dropdown
```

form.py

```
class leadForm(form.ModelForm):

    products = forms.MultipleChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all())
    technician = forms.CharField(max_length=30,choices=[(i.id,i.name) for i in Technician.objects.all().values('id','name') 
    class Meta:
        model = lead
        fields = ('name','technician')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [**`ModelMultipleChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField) here. The But in fact you do not need to implement the models yourself. You can simply let the Django logic do the work for you.

In order to give a textual representation at the HTML end, you can override the `__str__` functions of the models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Technician(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Lead(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    technician = models.ForeignKey(Technician, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
```

Then we can simply define our form with:

```
class LeadForm(form.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = '__all__'
```

> **Note**: usually classes are written in `PamelCase` and thus start with an **U**ppercase.

You can here use a class-based [**`CreateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) for example:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from app.models import Lead
from app.forms import LeafForm

class LeadCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Lead
    form_class = LeadForm
    template_name = 'create_lead.html'
```

Comment: do you think my model structure is right to achieve what I want?

Comment: can you share HTML file with me bcoz, I am able to create a lead in the admin panel but not using HTML. I am not getting any error and my multichoicefield is getting repeated number of times that of the values in products(eg  product values are 3 and dropdown lists are 3).I am sharing my HTML code snippet {{ form.product_name }} this is my product field inside form tag with method='POST'. I am not getting any error but not able to populate the database.

Comment: {{ form.products }}